# Counting number of points/lines/polygons contained within polygon when feature to count is from server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-query, count

I'm currently running a study where I need to query the number of points/lines/polygons that are contained within a project boundary - intersecting lines and polygons need to be counted as well. The features are linked to an agency server (operations allowed: Map (display), Query (Identify), Data (Find)). It would be extra helpful if I could get an output table that preserved the attributes, but I will walk away with just summing the points/lines/polygons contained within a polygon.

Answer (score 2):

The service will need to be published out as either a feature service or WFS.  This will allow you to export the data or perform spatial queries/selection on it.  If the service is not one of the two noted above then it is probably just a WMS service which essentially is just images of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is a MapService or Feature Service available to you, something like:

> "http://services.arcgis.com/oKgs2tbjK6zwTdvi/arcgis/rest/services/Major_World_Cities/FeatureServer/0"

In that case, you can register a GIS Server in the ArcCatalog:
As per above example enter only: 
http://services.arcgis.com/oKgs2tbjK6zwTdvi/arcgis/rest/services

and import data into ArcGIS Desktop. Then, you can work with the service or export the data to your local hard drive.